# Sum and average of numbers in Java

Tags: java, integer, sum, average

Here is the code but it's not optimized for all the exceptions. For example, if the user types 0 from the beginning, it will give the division by zero error and also I don't know why the sum of the numbers work.

Basically, I make num = 1 so it's different than 0 so the while loop can start, but in the end, I made sum = sum - 1; but it gave a wrong number.

Please help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        int num = 1;
        double average = 0.0;
        int soma = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a integer. 0 to exit.");

        while (num != 0) {
            num = scanner.nextInt();
            sum = sum + num;
            count++;
        }
        if (num == 0) {
            average = sum / (count -1); 
            System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is:  "+ soma);
            System.out.println("The average of the numbers is: "+ media);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your println should be sum and average not soma and media

Comment: When I was translating to english I forgot that xD

Answer (score 0):

change while to do while:

```
do {
    num = scanner.nextInt();
    sum = sum + num;
    count++;
}while (num != 0);
```

Change FROM:

```
average = sum / (count -1); 
System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is:  "+ soma);
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers is: "+ media);
```

TO:

```
 average = sum / (count); 
 System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is:  "+ sum);
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers is: "+ average);
```

it should work